# How we will find the particular location entrances gates on google api

Tags: php, google-maps, google-api

My questions is, How will we find the particular location entrances gates details on google API?

For example, Cricket stadium has four entrances, I need to find those four entrance details.

is this option is available in Google API?

Comment: This is not available in Google Maps APIs at the moment. I saw a similar feature request in Google issue tracker regarding boarding gates in airports: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68194442.

Comment: @xomena, thanks for your reply

Comment: @Yuvaraj Did u find any solution for this?

Comment: No @YaminiBalakrishnan

Comment: have you guys found anything on this?

Comment: @NIRAVBHAVSAR,As of now,google maps didn't provide this kind of location entrance details, So that we have achieved this by another alternative way,but in that custom way,we need to manually define the location and entrance details.